# Does Anyone Know a Fix for MongoDB Timeout Exceptions?

Tags: java, mongodb

I've been getting MongoDB Timeout Exceptions a lot more frequently lately. I code a discord bot that relies on it for most guild-based functions, and yesterday it hasn't been able to log into MongoDB at all using the Java driver. Just for a general overview of it, I'm using all up-to-date drivers and dependencies, and don't make use of any deprecated methods at all.

Since it isn't a problem inside my own code I have tried to tinker with the connection timeouts and different network settings.

Here are the error logs in the console (Disregard the logger messages):

```
2020-05-22 18:25 [main] CavenBot [INFO ] - Logging into databases...
2020-05-22 18:25 [main] CavenBot [INFO ] - Logging into MongoDB
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up TXT record for host discord-y3bzo.mongodb.net
    at com.mongodb.internal.dns.DefaultDnsResolver.resolveAdditionalQueryParametersFromTxtRecords(DefaultDnsResolver.java:131)
    at com.mongodb.ConnectionString.<init>(ConnectionString.java:378)
    at com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:61)
    at com.dragons0u1.CavenBot.main(CavenBot.java:37)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: DNS error [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out]; remaining name 'discord-y3bzo.mongodb.net'
    at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.query(DnsClient.java:313)
    at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.query(Resolver.java:81)
    at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_getAttributes(DnsContext.java:434)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:235)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:141)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:129)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:171)
    at com.mongodb.internal.dns.DefaultDnsResolver.resolveAdditionalQueryParametersFromTxtRecords(DefaultDnsResolver.java:114)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketReceiveOrPeekData(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:124)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:815)
    at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.doUdpQuery(DnsClient.java:423)
    at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.query(DnsClient.java:212)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The relevant errors here are:

`Unable to look up TXT record for host discord-y3bzo.mongodb.net`
`DNS error`
`java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out`

This suggests that you are using a `mongodb+srv` style connection string, and the DnsClient library is timing out trying to query the DNS server for the TXT record in needs in order to connect.

That is to say, this looks a lot like an issue with DNS resolver confguration, the DNS server, or the network connection to the DNS server.

Comment: Since I don't have too much experience with network issues, where would I go to change my DNS settings? I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: The system DNS resolver settings would be in the network and sharing center, but the Java virtual machine may or may not use those.

Comment: @Joe is this resolved? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: This isn't a problem with Atlas, it is a problem with the client-side DNS.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68903530/2282634