# Data fetching error from mongodb using express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am facing an error while fetching data from MongoDB using node & express. I am sharing two screenshots. One is an error message and another one is a code snippet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: does this help
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8811

Comment: The error message is not clear in your screenshot. I think it has to do something with the connection string uri format you are using for connecting to a remote cluster.

Comment: @prasad_ finally solved the problem. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68875026/error-querysrv-eservfail-mongodb-tcp-cluster0-abcd0-mongodb-net