# Only can connect to Mongo Cluster Using Google DNS

Tags: typescript, mongodb

I have use a Cluster in mongo and when i connnect to it, it said cant connect to the server and when i changed my DNS to google DNS so the problem is disappear.Its work properly in 8.8.8.8. How can I fix this because i cant access to some page in google DNS.

I have try to search for same problem but got nothing
[got this when not using google DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43zP1.png)

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68903530/2282634