# How to connect to Mongodb atlas in next_js 14 with mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, next.js13

I am unable to connect to **mongodb atlas** in next_js with **mongoose**. I am trying to connect with **vs Code connection string** but it is not working. I also tried to connect with **drivers connection string** but that also didn't work. I spent almost a whole day by trying different methods to solve but couldn't solve it. I will be thankful to you if you guys figure out that **what am i doing wrong?**

**1.env**

```
MONGODB_URI="mongodb+srv://MYUSERNAME:MYPASSWORD@cluster0.h1rv4ya.mongodb.net/crud_db"
```

**2.mongodb.js**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connectMongoDB = async () =\> {
try {
await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
console.log("connected to mongodb")
} catch (error) {
console.log(error)
}
}

export default connectMongoDB;
```

**3.topic.js**

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

const topicSchema = new Schema(
{
title: String,
description: String,
},
{
timestamps: true,
}
);

const Topic = mongoose.models.Topic || mongoose.model("Topic", topicSchema);

export default Topic;
```

**4.route.js**

```
import connectMongoDB from "@/libs/mongodb";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import Topic from "@/models/topic";

export async function POST (req) {
const {title, description} = await req.json();
await connectMongoDB();
await Topic.create({title, description});
return NextResponse.json({message: "Topic created"}, {status: 201});
}
```

I tried to connect to mongodb atlas in next_js with mongoose with vs code connection string but it is not working. The error I am getting is given below;

**5.error**

```
⨯ MongooseError: Operation `topics.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\WEB DEVELOPMENT\FRONT_END PROJECTS\NEXT JS PROJECTS\crud_app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:186:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
failed to connect Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0.h1rv4ya.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:251:17)
    at QueryReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'queryTxt',
  hostname: 'cluster0.h1rv4ya.mongodb.net'
}
```

I've whitelisted my IP address and I also changed my DNS settings but that didn't work either. when I try to connect to the mongodb installed on my computer, that works but the mongo atlas doesn't work. I don't think if there is any mistake in my code but still I've provided my code files so that you can figure out that what's going wrong.

Comment: `queryTxt ETIMEOUT` indicates a DNS error while looking up the TXT record.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68903530/2282634

Comment: I normally use mongoose for such purpose, as it is easy and handy for doing such tasks.