# https://next-auth.js.org/errors#adapter_error_getsessionanduser queryTxt EREFUSED cluster0.1gxvcxr.mongodb.net

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js

when i start to login in my application then show this error and it comes to time to after some time if we refresh

```
[next-auth][error][adapter_error_getSessionAndUser] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#adapter_error_getsessionanduser queryTxt EREFUSED cluster0.1gxvcxr.mongodb.net {
  message: 'queryTxt EREFUSED cluster0.1gxvcxr.mongodb.net',
  stack: 'Error: queryTxt EREFUSED cluster0.1gxvcxr.mongodb.net\n' +
    '    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:275:17)\n' +
    '    at QueryReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)',
  name: 'Error'
}
[next-auth][error][SESSION_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#session_error queryTxt EREFUSED cluster0.1gxvcxr.mongodb.net Error: queryTxt EREFUSED cluster0.1gxvcxr.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:275:17)
    at QueryReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  name: 'GetSessionAndUserError',
  code: 'EREFUSED'
}
```

find the solution for this errror

Comment: Does your app connect to the DB _sometimes or never_? Your application can't connect to the Mongo Atlas DB. [Add your app's IP address to the IP Access list](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security/ip-access-list/#modify-ip-access-list-entries).

Comment: queryTxt EREFUSED is a DNS failure.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68903530/2282634