# Unable to connect ot Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

when i run my backend file using nodemon app.js =>This Error Occurs

```
Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.brbkwbs.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:275:17) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.brbkwbs.mongodb.net'
```

This error is not resolving even i have upgraded my node version to latest...All packges are updated cluster configurations are accurate but dont know why its not working.......am i missing something do anybody knows about it?

Comment: Check you connection string properties, I don't think `_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.brbkwbs.mongodb.net` is a valid server name or MongoDB instance.

Comment: That is the SRV record.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68903530/2282634