(Vercel/ MongoDB): Failed to connect with the database: querySrv ETIMEOUT
I can run my ExpressJS API locally using the "vercel dev" command, but when I try to deploy it ("vercel" command) I get this error: "Failed to connect with the database: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.ibujag1.mongodb.net"
I am using the MONGODB_URI automatically created by the MongoDB integration with Vercel.
Vercel automatically created a user in MongoDB's Database Access and I already added the ip 0.0.0.0/0 to the Network Access.
Here is my code: https://github.com/xdanrj/stancapapi
The MONGODB_URI looks like: mongodb+srv://vercel-admin-user:PASSWORDHERE@cluster0.ibujag1.mongodb.net/Stancap?retryWrites=true&w=majority

That is a DNS error, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68903530/2282634

I already have tried the older connection strings (actually needed to select mongodb version 2.2.12 to get the older string one. For you info., Mongodb is at 5.5 now) and I got no data coming from the API even locally. I already have tried Vercel and Netlify. It's possibly to all sites have the same DNS issue?

Using the older connection string would not have generated a querySrv response.  Did it have a different error message?

Using the older connect. string I got no data coming from the API and any error (using the newest connect. string LOCALLY the API working perfectly. I also tried deploying in Netlify and its failed too: "Failed during stage 'building site': Command did not finish within the time limit. Execution timed out after 17m59.784522081s" (yes, after 18minutes)

I used Docker to create a container of the app and it worked.
